# Java Interface with generics shall accept subclass as typeargument

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, generic-type-argument

I have the following class hierarchy by now:

```java
interface Interface<T> {
    boolean isGreaterThan(T other);
}
```

```java
class Base implements Interface<Base> {
    public boolean isGreaterThan(Base other) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
class Subclass extends Base {
    ... //note that I dont need to implement or overwrite isGreaterThan() here
}
```

```java
class Wrapper<E extends Interface<E>> {
    protected List<E> list;
    ...
}
```

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper<Subclass> = new Wrapper<Subclass>(); //This line produces the error
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Type parameter 'Subclass' is not within its bound; should implement 'Interface<Subclass>'
```

My Question is: How can I tell java, that the Interface should accept any element E which extends T? Or is the reason in Wrapper? I tried for the Wrapper:

```java
class Wrapper<E extends Interface<? extends E>> {}
```

which rather produced errors in the body of wrapper, and did not change the original error.

```java
Wrapper<Base> wrapper = new Wrapper<Base>();
```

works just fine...
how can I make

```java
Wrapper<Subclass> wrapper = new Wrapper<Subclass>();
```

work as well?
Is there a clean way without any casts? (Wildcards allowed)

Thanks!

Comment: `class Wrapper<E extends Interface<? super E>>`

Comment: This does not change anything, thank you for your help!

Comment: `<? super E>`  :) see also example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

Comment: I tried it, but the error is still there ;-)

Comment: Ohhh, I had other errors which complicated your suggestion, but I could figure out, this was because of inner-class generics, and I just had to put your '? extends' solution there too... now the whole thing works! Thanks so much!

Do you want to post this as answer, so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
class Wrapper<E extends Interface<? super E>>
```

just like `Comparable`, it is intuitively a ['contra-variant'](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Variance) type, therefore in most cases it should be used with `<? super>`. For example [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Comment: By the way: I had an inner class, which uses the same interface, thus I had to add <? super E> to the Inner Class definition as well!

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
class Base<T extends Base<T>> implements Interface<T> {
    public boolean isGreaterThan(T other) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Subclass extends Base<Subclass> {
    ... //note that I dont need to implement or overwrite isGreaterThan() here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the first approach! It works for every subclass now, but no more for the base class itself?

I mean: Wrapper<Base> wrapper = new Wrapper<Base>() will produce the error now, while Wrapper<Subclass> will work :/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Because `Base` is now a generic class, so `Base` without a type argument, which you are using in `Wrapper<Base>`, is a [raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: I tried to figure out a workaround, but I failed. Can you give me perhaps another hint? I would be grateful!

Comment: The answer of Zhong Yu works for every case! Thanks nevertheless!